# Cakephp maximum depth reached and recursivity is 2

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, recursive-query

I want to show an attribute id of `BiensPersonne` but it shows me in debug maximum depth reached and the recursivity is 2.

When I write

```
Debugger::dump($this->
          Reservation->
          find('all', array('contain' => array('Bien.BiensPersonne.id'))));
```

it shows me this:

```
array( (int) 0 => 
    array(
        'Reservation' => array(
            'idReser' => '1',
            'dateReserDu' => '2016-04-23',
            'dateReserAu' => '2016-04-27',
            'montantAPaye' => '500',
            'etatReservation' => 'Reserve',
            'iddev' => '0',
            'idBien' => '9',
            'id' => '24'
        ),
        'Bien' => array(
            'idBien' => '9',
            'designBien' => 'Petit coeur a TUNIS ville',
            'aPropos' => 'De Host ,
            'capaciteAccueil' => '3',
            'nbSalleBain' => '1',
            'nbChambre' => '2',
            'nbLits' => '3',
            'description' => 'De Host a Milan beaucoup apprecie, avec environ ,
            'adresse' => 'rue ladikiya',
            'immeuble' => '',
            'affichable' => false,
            'affichablePageAccueil' => false,
            'idtypelogement' => '1',
            'idVille' => '14',
            'idPays' => '1',
            'idTypeBien' => '2',
            'posLat' => '36.8065',
            'posLong' => '10.1815',
            'BiensPersonne' => array([maximum depth reached])
         )
      ),
```

my controller

```
public function index_hote() {
$this->Reservation->recursive = 2;
$this->loadModel("BiensPersonne");
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.0.Personne.id')) {
    $options = $this->
               BiensPersonne->
               findByPersonneId($this->Session->read('Auth.User.0.Personne.id')); 
    $this->loadModel("Personne");
    $biens = $this->
             Personne->
             findById($options['BiensPersonne']['personne_id']);
    $this->loadModel("Personne");
    $reservations = $this->
                    Reservation->
                    find('all', 
                         array(
                         'conditions' => array('Reservation.idBien' => 22),
                         'contain' => array('Bien' => array('BiensPersonne'))
                        )
                    );
}
```

in the model reservation

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Personne' => array(
        'className' => 'Personne',
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Bien' => array(
        'className' => 'Bien',
        'foreignKey' => 'idBien',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

in my model Bien

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'BiensPersonne' 
);
```

i want to have BiensPersonne.id from Reservation using Bien

**How can I make this work?**

Comment: please post your code

Comment: i edit my post. Plz see my code

Comment: It's related to the debugger, not to your code. You just have to set a higher depth in the debugger i.e. `Debugger::dump($yourData, 4)`. See my previos comment

Comment: when i write Debugger::dump($this->Reservation->find('all',array('contain' => array('Bien'=>array('BiensPersonne.personne_id'=>$this->Session->read('Auth.User.0.Personne.id'))))));
 it show me a message error "Warning (512): Model "BiensPersonne" is not associated with model "1" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 342]" what should i do?

Comment: This is a different question. If my comment solved your problem consider closing this question as it is a duplicate and open a new one

Comment: ok thx my probleme is solved thx you very much